# Django-Allauth equivalent for Django Ninja?

Tags: python, django, authentication, single-sign-on, django-ninja

I am developing a REST API for web application in Django Ninja and one of our project's assumptions is possibility of using Google SSO for authentication.

**Is there any equivalent of Django-Allauth for Django-Ninja?** I haven't found anything similar and to be honest I have no idea on how to process that in Django Ninja.

Thanks in advance. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> Django-Allauth

or

> dj-rest-auth.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).